# Automatic tests for shell scripts with Python

Tags: python

I am seeking an elegant solution for automating the tests for a command line tool with sub-commands and multiple options. So far, the closest thing I could find is Mercurial’s [testing infrastructure](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WritingTests#Writing_a_shell_script_test):

the run_tests.py script can run shell script tests, python tests in a unified way. The verifications of tests are mainly for comparing commands’ output with pre-defined ones and checking the commands’ exit statuses.

However, after checking the source of run_tests.py in mercurial, it’s over complicated with years evolution, and since Mercurial is designed for Python 2.4-2.7, new features since 2.5 are not used, which makes the code a little bit outdated, for example, all the actual command runs are wrapped in its home-grown *Popen4*:

```
processlock = threading.Lock()

closefds = os.name == 'posix'
def open4(cmd, wd, timeout):
    processlock.acquire()
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, bufsize=-1, cwd=wd,
                         close_fds=closefds,
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    processlock.release()

    p.fromchild = p.stdout
    p.tochild = p.stdin
    p.childerr = p.stderr

    p.timeout = False
    if timeout:
        def t():
            start = time.time()
            while time.time() - start < timeout and p.returncode is None:
                time.sleep(.1)
            p.timeout = True
            if p.returncode is None:
                terminate(p)
        threading.Thread(target=t).start()

return p
```

There are even no attributes like fromchild, tochild in newer versions now, what should be equivalent piece with modern python?

I may roll my own version of simplified run_tests.py with modern python, however, before I do that, I would like to know if there are better existing solutions to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

What I need is:

1. An isolated environment to run a series of shell commands separately
2. The ability to check command outputs and exit statuses
3. It would be better to provide some callback or hooks for further verifications for some of the tests (the commands with side effects).

Please kindly let me know if you have any experiences to share or any suggestions on this.

Comment: `fromchild`, `tochild`, and `childerr` are attributes made by the script itself, not something built into Python.

Comment: @Amber, thanks for your comments, Um, I would say it's not a very good coding style then.

Comment: I don't know that it's necessarily bad, it's just adding an alias to stdin/stdout/stderr making it clearer where the pipes are going. Though the subprocess docs have this interesting note: Warning Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.